# query object attributs (as data in a column) Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, object, oracle-sqldeveloper

I imported a dataset that has a object in the column GENRES and I'm wondering if there is a (beginner's) way to query the data inside each entry.

[{"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 10751, "name": "Family"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}]

For example, if I would want to query all the movies having the "id": 12.

The dataset comes from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/tmdb/tmdb-movie-metadata)

Answer (score 0):

If you store the data with an `IS JSON` constraint, then you can use [JSON_TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/JSON_TABLE.html#GUID-3C8E63B5-0B94-4E86-A2D3-3D4831B67C62) to expand the JSON into columns.

```
--Create a table.
create table tmdb(movie_id number, genres clob check (genres is json));

--Insert a test row.
insert into tmdb
values(1, '[{"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 10751, "name": "Family"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}]');

--Use JSON_TABLE to convert JSON to relational data.
select movie_id, id, name
from tmdb,
    json_table
    (
        genres, '$[*]'
        columns
        (
            id number path '$.id',
            name varchar2(4000) path '$.name'
        )
    ) as jt;

--Results:

MOVIE_ID   ID      NAME
--------   -----   ---------
       1      12   Adventure
       1   10751   Family
       1      14   Fantasy
```